# how do I add the image to my cart using javascript (Front-End Only)?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I have a working cart but would like to add the image of my product as well as the title and price but not really sure how to do it. Everything I tried so far has just broken the code. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is my single product page with my cart and my javascript file. Im only looking for front-end help here as I havent gotten round to the back end yet

```
var shoppingCart = (function() {

  cart = [];


  function Item(name, image, price, count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.price = price;
    this.count = count;
  }


  function saveCart() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }


  function loadCart() {
    cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
  }
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") != null) {
    loadCart();
  }

  var obj = {};


  obj.addItemToCart = function(name, image, price, count) {
    for (var item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart[item].count++;
        saveCart();
        return;
      }
    }
    var item = new Item(name, price, count);
    cart.push(item);
    saveCart();
  }

  obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
    for (var i in cart) {
      if (cart[i].name === name) {
        cart[i].count = count;
        break;
      }
    }
  };

  obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
    for (var item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart[item].count--;
        if (cart[item].count === 0) {
          cart.splice(item, 1);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    saveCart();
  }


  obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
    for (var item in cart) {
      if (cart[item].name === name) {
        cart.splice(item, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    saveCart();
  }


  obj.clearCart = function() {
    cart = [];
    saveCart();
  }


  obj.totalCount = function() {
    var totalCount = 0;
    for (var item in cart) {
      totalCount += cart[item].count;
    }
    return totalCount;
  }


  obj.totalCart = function() {
    var totalCart = 0;
    for (var item in cart) {
      totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
    }
    return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
  }


  obj.listCart = function() {
    var cartCopy = [];
    for (i in cart) {
      item = cart[i];
      itemCopy = {};
      for (p in item) {
        itemCopy[p] = item[p];

      }
      itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
      cartCopy.push(itemCopy)
    }
    return cartCopy;
  }


  return obj;
})();
$('.add-to-cart').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var price = Number($(this).data('price'));
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
  displayCart();
});





$('.clear-cart').click(function() {
  shoppingCart.clearCart();
  displayCart();
});


function displayCart() {
  var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
  var output = "";
  for (var i in cartArray) {
    output += "<tr>" +
      "<td>" + cartArray[i].name + "</td>" +
      "<td>(" + cartArray[i].price + ")</td>" +
      "<td><div class='input-group'><button class='minus-item input-group-addon btn 
    btn - primary ' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">-</button>" +
      "<input type='number' class='item-count form-control' data-name='" +
      cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>" +
      "<button class='plus-item btn btn-primary input-group-addon' data-name=" +
      cartArray[i].name + ">+</button></div></td>" +
      "<td><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name +
      ">X</button></td>" +
      " = " +
      "<td>" + cartArray[i].total + "</td>" +
      "</tr>";
  }
  $('.show-cart').html(output);
  $('.total-cart').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
  $('.total-count').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
}



$('.show-cart').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
  displayCart();
})



$('.show-cart').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
  displayCart();
})

$('.show-cart').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name')
  shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
  displayCart();
})


$('.show-cart').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).data('name');
  var count = Number($(this).val());
  shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
  displayCart();
});

displayCart();
```

and my single product page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/
jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" i.ntegrity="sha384A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/
nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}
</script>

<style>


body {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.sidepanel {
  width: 350px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.sidepanel a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidepanel a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidepanel .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

.show-cart li {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card-price {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery-hightlight {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50%;
}

.image-preview {
  display: flex;
  display: width:: 100%;
}

.image-preview img {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img.image-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
     A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "250px";
      }

      function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
      }
    </script>
    
    <nav class="navbar-buttons">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#cart">Cart (<span class="total-count"></span>)</button><button class="clear-cart btn btn-danger">Clear Cart</button></div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card" style="width: 650px; text-align: center;">
            <img class="gallery-hightlight" src="/Volumes/Untitled/coding/images/bowie- 
      big.jpeg" width="500px" alt="David Bowie Pop Art">
            <div class="image-preview">
              <img src="/volumes/Untitled/coding/images/bowie-small.jpeg" class="image-active" width="250px" alt="" />
              <img src="/volumes/Untitled/coding/images/bowie2-small.jpeg" width="250px" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork floral painting on wooden canvas with an original pop art style David Bowie Mugshot on top painting is framed with a red baroque style frame including the words deadly flowers bloom
                around frame</p>
              <p class="card-price">Price: £200</p>
              <a href="#" data-name="Bowie Art" data-image="/volumes/Untitled/coding/images/Boy- 
      small.jpeg" data-price="200" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">x</a>
        <div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cart</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                <table class="show-cart table">

                </table>
                <div>Total price: £<span class="total-cart"></span></div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--
       <script src="./shop.js"></script>
       <script src="imageGallery.js"></script>
       -->
</body>
```

Comment: It's invalid HTML to have your head inside your body. You're also not closing the head. I suggest a review of your document structure.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question is rather broad. You need to revise to ask something more specific and let us know exactly how it's failing.

Comment: I will suggest that you wouldn't normally "add" images to a cart. You should be adding products by ID and getting assets related to that ID by API call or whatever. Don't pass image paths explicitly.

Comment: thank you - just edited my code. I didnt realise it cut the top off it. How would I go about doing what you suggest in your 3rd comment? Thanks

Comment: That's too big of a question. I haven't studied the massive amount of code you've posted and don't know enough about your backend.

Comment: ok, thanks. Smaller question - Instead Please can you assist me with adding the image to my cart? Ive already got the name and price- how do I include the image as well?

Comment: That's the same question, but questions should not be posed in comments _at all_. Your post needs to contain your question and all necessary information. See [ask] again if you need a refresher.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but originally you were talking about the back-end and Im just after how I go about this on  purely front end. If that makes sense. Ill update my question to ask only front end help